# How to generate a sequence of numbers on every refresh in javascript

Tags: javascript, sequence

In javascript we can generate a random number using Random() function. But how to generate a series of natural numbers on every refresh. 
     Take a range 1 to 10. First I should get 1 and then on every refresh 2, 3, 4, ... should be generated. Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP protocol is stateless, meaning on every refresh your browser/server forgets about the previous view. Thus your page on its own cannot have "memory" and remember what was the previous number.

Of course there are multiple a little bit more sophisticated solutions. E.g. you can use [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies), [httpsession](/questions/tagged/httpsession) or maybe even some URL tricks (hash tags, query parameters). The scenario is always the same: when rendering/entering the page check the previous value and render/display the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to store which number the user last saw with cookies. On the first load, your script checks and sees there is no cookie, so it sets the number to one, and saves that in a cookie. On the next load, it sees that there is a cookie that says "1", so it increments that and displays "2", saving *that* in a cookie, and so on. Once it gets to ten, (you said a range from 1-10), what the script does is up to you.